# Scripting with public game commands

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

So here is the problem:

I script stuff in source engine with commands that are public. If you enable the console you can write those in there and use them.

Examples:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/146693/how-can-i-toggle-cycle-through-settings

[Bind a key for multiple units to use the same spell](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142898/bind-a-key-for-multiple-units-to-use-the-same-spell)

[Hotkey to send hero back to base](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/128460/hotkey-to-send-hero-back-to-base)

Now people told me that those are off topic and as you see one got put on hold as offtopic. Therefore it was migrated to gamedev. (Since i was not familiar with migration i crossposted it and let the one on arqade get deleted)

So I flagged all scripting questions as off but the other got declined....

I want a clear line on this!

Comment: Related: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7661/51318

Comment: I'm not seeing any of those migrated to Gamedev.

Comment: I believe one was deleted, according to a comment it was flagged for deletion by its author.

Comment: The distinction I try to draw when seeing these questions (others may disagree) is: are you trying to fundementally change how the game works, in order to create a new game? or are you trying to add functionality to a game that otherwise remains the same? If the former: GameDev. If the latter, Arqade

Comment: Here is where it got crossposted, and the original deleted after the fact: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67550/how-can-i-toggle-cycle-through-settings

Comment: I deleted that one because I was not yet familiar with migration and therefore cross posted it instead. It was put on hold as off

Comment: @Wandang, it's not a huge deal, and it seems like you figured it out after the initial question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my opinion, config scripts for games are more in the realm of gaming expertise, and less in the realms of game development or programming expertise.  Therefore, I consider them on-topic for Arqade.

The scripting language and the specific application of the language is only used for configuration files meant to be edited by end users.  Someone who is an expert in writing games or writing other software is probably not going to be as familiar with it as an end user would be.

The fundamental purpose of the language is to macro or change the function of particular keys, which is a fundamental part of many questions on the site.

A quick search for "hotkey" on the main site brings up 23 pages of results, many of which reference key bind scripts and so forth:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=hotkey